# Given an array with the path, set value in JSON object

Tags: arrays, json, coffeescript

Given a JSON object: `{"a": {"b": [{"c": "123"}]}}` and an array with the path through the JSON `["a", "b", "0", "c"]`, how can I modify the final value of "123"?

`json["a"]["b"][0]["c"] = "abc"` is what I am trying to accomplish, but the array with the path is completely variable. Each item in the path array will always be in the JSON object.

I am working in CoffeeScript, but psuedo code would be just as helpful

Comment: Surely there's something I don't understand, `json["a"]["b"][0]["c"] = "abc"` should be fine, what do you mean with "the array with the path completely variable"?

Comment: the path might be `["a", "b", "0", "c"]`, but it could be `["x"]`, or `["g","h","j","k","l"]`

It describes the structure of the json, which will be different

Comment: Still I don't understand it, sorry. Maybe it's because I have no idea of `coffeescript`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved Bobby's answer and wrote it in CoffeeScript. It works well.

```
setValue = (obj, path, value) ->
  path.forEach (val, index, path) ->
    if path.length - 1 != index 
      obj = obj[val]
    else
      obj[val] = value

json = "a": "b": ["c": "123"]
path = ["a", "b", "0", "c"]
value = "abc"

setValue json, path, value

console.log json["a"]["b"][0]["c"]  # => "abc"
```

I hope it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your need to drill into the object using all but the last path item. Then use last path item to set the value. In JavaScript, you could create tbe following function for setting the value...

```
function setValue(obj, path, value) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
        obj = obj[path[i]];
    }
    obj[path[i]] = value;
}
```

You could then call the function using...

```
var obj = {"a": {"b": [{"c": "123"}]}};
var path = ["a", "b", "0", "c"];
var value = "abc";
setValue(obj, path, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a more general, and much more complex, answer. This is what I used in [excel-as-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-as-json). See that link or the test cases below for examples of the json dotted string key path syntax.

```
BOOLTEXT = ['true', 'false']
BOOLVALS = {'true': true, 'false': false}

isArray = (obj) ->
  Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) is '[object Array]'

# Extract key name and array index from names[1] or names[]
# return [keyIsList, keyName, index]
# for names[1] return [true,  keyName,  index]
# for names[]  return [true,  keyName,  undefined]
# for names    return [false, keyName,  undefined]
parseKeyName = (key) ->
  index = key.match(/\[(\d+)\]$/)
  switch
    when index             then [true, key.split('[')[0], Number(index[1])]
    when key[-2..] is '[]' then [true, key[...-2], undefined]
    else                        [false, key, undefined]

# Convert a list of values to a list of more native forms
convertValueList = (list) ->
  (convertValue(item) for item in list)

# Convert values to native types
# Assume: all values from the excel module are text
convertValue = (value) ->
  if isFinite(value)
    Number(value)
  else
    testVal = value.toLowerCase()
    if testVal in BOOLTEXT
      BOOLVALS[testVal]
    else
      value

# Assign a value to a dotted property key - set values on sub-objects
assign = (obj, key, value) ->
  # On first call, a key is a string. Recursed calls, a key is an array
  key = key.split '.' unless typeof key is 'object'
  # Array element accessors look like phones[0].type or aliases[]
  [keyIsList, keyName, index] = parseKeyName key.shift()

  if key.length
    if keyIsList
      # if our object is already an array, ensure an object exists for this index
      if isArray obj[keyName]
        unless obj[keyName][index]
          obj[keyName].push({}) for i in [obj[keyName].length..index]
      # else set this value to an array large enough to contain this index
      else
        obj[keyName] = ({} for i in [0..index])
      assign obj[keyName][index], key, value
    else
      obj[keyName] ?= {}
      assign obj[keyName], key, value
  else
    if keyIsList and index?
      console.error "WARNING: Unexpected key path terminal containing an indexed list for <#{keyName}>"
      console.error "WARNING: Indexed arrays indicate a list of objects and should not be the last element in a key path"
      console.error "WARNING: The last element of a key path should be a key name or flat array. E.g. alias, aliases[]"
    if (keyIsList and not index?)
      obj[keyName] = convertValueList(value.split ';')
    else
      obj[keyName] = convertValue value

# Test cases
obj = {}
assign obj, 'firstName', 'Jihad'
assign obj, 'lastName', 'Saladin'
assign obj, 'address.street', '12 Beaver Court'
assign obj, 'address.city', 'Snowmass'
assign obj, 'address.state', 'CO'
assign obj, 'address.zip', '81615'
assign obj, 'isEmployee', 'true'
assign obj, 'phones[0].type', 'home'
assign obj, 'phones[0].number', '123.456.7890'
assign obj, 'phones[1].type',  'work'
assign obj, 'phones[1].number', '098.765.4321'
assign obj, 'aliases[]', 'stormagedden;bob'
console.log JSON.stringify obj, null, 2
```

produces

```
{
  "firstName": "Jihad",
  "lastName": "Saladin",
  "address": {
    "street": "12 Beaver Court",
    "city": "Snowmass",
    "state": "CO",
    "zip": 81615
  },
  "isEmployee": true,
  "phones": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "123.456.7890"
    },
    {
      "type": "work",
      "number": "098.765.4321"
    }
  ],
  "aliases": [
    "stormagedden",
    "bob"
  ]
}
```